Проблема с cx_freeze и модулями
Структура проекта
**main**
|-.gitignore
|-CHANGELOG.md
|-CITATION.cff
|-LICENSE
|-README.md
└───building(folder)
| |-setup.py
|
└───src(folder)
  |-__init__.py
  |-acc_connect.py
  |-app.py
  |-resources_rc.py
  |-icons(folder)
  └───modules(folder)
      |-__init__.py
      |-exceptions.py
      |-functions.py
      |-iSender.py

Пытаюсь с помощью cx_freeze создать .exe файл, жалуется, что не удается импортировать модуль "modules". Внутри этой папки находятся файлы, непосредственно тесно связанные с программой и импортируемые в app.py (from modules.functions import * и тд и тп)
Не пойму, что ему не нравится, может кто увидит проблему
Файл setup.py
# coding: utf-8

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

executables = [Executable(script="src/app.py", target_name="STB.exe", 
 icon='src/icons/ico.ico', base='gui']

 excludes = ["src/__pycache__", "src/modules/__pycache__", "src/.venv", 
        "src/auth", "src/export", "__init__.py", ".gitignore", "CHANGELOG.md", 
        "CITATION.cff", "LICENSE", "README.md", "building", "building/setup.py"]

 includes = ["steampy"]

 zip_include_packages = ['steampy']

 include_file = ["src/acc_connect.py", "src/dynamic_layout.ui", 
 "src/modules/exceptions.py", "src/modules/functions.py", "src/modules/iSender.py", 
 "src/resources_rc.py", "src/resources.qrc", "src/__init__.py", "src/modules/"]

options = {
 'build_exe': {
    'include_msvcr': False, #По дефолту использую True, False чтобы видно было сборку среди всей параши msvcr
    'excludes': excludes,
    'includes': includes,
    'include_files': include_file,
    'zip_include_packages': zip_include_packages,
    'build_exe': 'build_Windows',
    }
}

setup(name='STB',
    version='1.2.5',
    description='STB.exe',
    executables=executables,
    options=options)

Ошибка: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'
Это единственное, что выдает из ошибки
